# How to apply group by clause

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Query

```
SELECT 
    TIMECARD.EMP_ID, TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID, TIMECARD.TIMECARD_STATUS,
    TASK.MAN_HOURS
FROM 
    TRN_TIMECARD_ACTIVITY ACT
INNER JOIN 
    TRN_TIMECARD TIMECARD ON TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID = ACT.TIMECARD_ID
INNER JOIN 
    TRN_TIMECARD_TASK TASK ON TASK.TIMECARD_ID = TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID 
WHERE 
    ACT.TIMECARD_STATUS IN ('AP','RE')
```

OUTPUT:

```
61  42  AP  9
61  42  AP  9
61  43  AP  9
61  43  AP  9
61  47  AP  7
```

I have to get group by `emp_id` and calculate `sum(man_hours)`.

How to get value like below

```
61  42  AP  52
```

Comment: how did you get `52`?

Comment: Why are you taking 42 after grouping?

Answer (score 1):

...don't see how the middle two columns figure in your group, so I'd do:

```
SELECT        TIMECARD.EMP_ID, SUM(TASK.MAN_HOURS)
FROM          TRN_TIMECARD_ACTIVITY ACT
INNER JOIN    TRN_TIMECARD TIMECARD ON TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID=ACT.TIMECARD_ID
INNER JOIN    TRN_TIMECARD_TASK TASK ON TASK.TIMECARD_ID=TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID 
WHERE         ACT.TIMECARD_STATUS IN('AP','RE')
GROUP BY      TIMECARD.EMP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your desired result, I see that you give the `Minimum` (*lowest*) value of the column `TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID` and the `Sum` (*total*) of `TASK.MAN_HOURS`. (*but i don't get why you get a value of 52*)

```
SELECT  TIMECARD.EMP_ID,
        MIN(TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID) time_card,
        TIMECARD.TIMECARD_STATUS,
        SUM(TASK.MAN_HOURS) totalHours
FROM    TRN_TIMECARD_ACTIVITY ACT
        INNER JOIN TRN_TIMECARD TIMECARD ON TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID=ACT.TIMECARD_ID
        INNER JOIN TRN_TIMECARD_TASK TASK ON TASK.TIMECARD_ID=TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID 
WHERE   ACT.TIMECARD_STATUS IN('AP','RE')
GROUP   BY TIMECARD.EMP_ID, TIMECARD.TIMECARD_STATUS
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you...taking minimum of TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID

```
SELECT TIMECARD.EMP_ID,
       MIN(TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID) TIMECARD_ID, 
       TIMECARD.TIMECARD_STATUS,
       SUM(TASK.MAN_HOURS) HOURS 
FROM TRN_TIMECARD_ACTIVITY ACT
INNER JOIN
TRN_TIMECARD TIMECARD ON TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID=ACT.TIMECARD_ID
INNER JOIN
TRN_TIMECARD_TASK TASK ON TASK.TIMECARD_ID=TIMECARD.TIMECARD_ID 
WHERE ACT.TIMECARD_STATUS IN('AP','RE')
GROUP BY TIMECARD.EMP_ID,TIMECARD.TIMECARD_STATUS
```